# React app under Plesk static assets are not reachable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, plesk

I am trying to run a React app under Plesk Windows hosting. The React app was created by the command **create-react-app**.

I created a static assets directory called build with the command **npm run build**.

I created a file called server.js in the project root directory with the following content:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Under Plesk Node.js, the application startup script is set to start with this file server.js.

With the homepage set to "homepage": "./build" in package.json, when running the app in the browser and inspecting the debug output, console logging is as follows:

[image]

The static assets are not reachable because of the faulty path /build/build/static. The path should simply be: /build/static.

With the homepage set to "homepage": "./" in package.json, when running the app in the browser and inspecting the debug output, console logging is as follows:

[image]

Now, the static assets are not reachable because the path is set to merely /static, and not /build/static.

Answer (score 0):

delete homepage setting in package.json and "npm run build" again

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// set * to serve index.html everytime
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```